# How to mount this LVM volume?

Tags: linux, lvm

I was trying to follow [this article](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-mount-linux-lvm-volume-partitions-linux), but it looks like I failed:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/vda: 171.8 GB, 171798691840 bytes
16 heads, 63 sectors/track, 332881 cylinders, total 335544320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a5206

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1              63    37998046    18998992   83  Linux
/dev/vda2        37998592    38998015      499712   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/vda3        38998016   335544319   148273152   8e  Linux LVM
# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/vda3  vd   lvm2 a--  141.40g 141.40g
# lvdisplay /dev/vd
#
# vgchange vd -a y
0 logical volume(s) in volume group "vd" now active
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have any logical volumes in your volume group.
You need the `lvcreate` command for that.

Frankly, I don't like doing disk partitioning from CLI. KVPM is an awesome GUI for LVM if you can get your hands on it. It's much more intuitive, you actually "see" your layout, and you can learn the CLI commands later if you need to script things.